# static struct declaration in C

Tags: c, static

I attempted to make a `struct` declaration `static` (so it can only be used within the files):

```
static typedef struct
{
   int foo;
} MyStruct;

static MyStruct[5];
```

(This is in test_struct.c)
When I compiled the thing, I got this error:

```
test_struct.c:12: multiple storage classes in declaration of `MyStruct'
```

I figured if I remove the `static` before `typedef struct ...`, it'll work, but what should I do if I really want to make the struct declaration static?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **declare variables as static**.

```
static MyStruct ms[5];
```

I usually do it like this,

```
typedef struct{
   int foo;
} MyStruct;

static MyStruct   myStruct[5];
```

Comment: Are you sure about the first part? Got a referene on that?

Comment: Not really. It's technically not forbidden by the syntax rules, but it also has no effects.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Yes, that worked, as I mentioned in the question. But the real question was that 'Is it possible to make `MyStruct` a static type.

Comment: no **static type** is not possible. Only static instances possible.